# Retrofit Android: How to map an array of values?

Tags: java, json, serialization, retrofit2

The endpoint returns a JSON response like below.

```
{
   "students":[
      [
         1,
         "Tom",
         18,
         "USA"
      ],
      [
         2,
         "Linda",
         21,
         "Mexico"
      ]
   ],
   "other":[
      "100",
      "400"
   ]
}
```

Let's say I only care about the `students` in the response and want to get a list of students. In the response, each student is represented as an array of values without a key:

```
[id, name, age, country]
```

(Assume there can be more fields but the order of fields is the same for every student)

```
class GetStudentsResponse {
  Student[] students;
}

class Student {
  String name;
  int age;
  // HOW CAN I TELL RETROFIT TO MAP CORRECTLY HERE?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit is not doing JSON (de)serialization itself - it uses another library, which is by default GSON.

In the input you have, you actually have an array (`[id, name, age, country]`), so you cannot parse it to an object using serializers that GSON generates by default (you would need to have JSON object).

In that case you could either parse that array to a `String[]` and the parse it to `Student` or **write your own GSON serializer for that input**. I would recommend the second solution:

```
JsonSerializer<Student> serializer = new JsonSerializer<Merchant>() {  
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Student src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        // Implement serializer here
    }
};


JsonDeserializer<Student> serializer = new JsonDeserializer<Student>() {  
    @Override
    public JsonElement deserialize(Student src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        // Implement deserializer here
    }
};
```

You would use it like this:  `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Student.class, serializer).create();`

Another approach is to create a `TypeAdapter`. Here is an example from [Gson documentation](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html):

```
 public class PointAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Point> {
   public Point read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
     if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
       reader.nextNull();
       return null;
     }
     String xy = reader.nextString();
     String[] parts = xy.split(",");
     int x = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
     int y = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
     return new Point(x, y);
   }
   public void write(JsonWriter writer, Point value) throws IOException {
     if (value == null) {
       writer.nullValue();
       return;
     }
     String xy = value.getX() + "," + value.getY();
     writer.value(xy);
   }
 }
```

Comment: where do I put these code?  when I build Retrofit object?  Also, I see other people use something called TypeAdapterFactory.  Is it the same thing you are talking about?

Comment: `TypeAdapterFactory` is useful when you have nested objects and you want to reuse existing type adapter. In your case, you don't have an object (that would be enclosed in `{}` and have field names like `"age"`), so I don't think this is recommended in your case but I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Retrofit 2.**
When endpoint response body starts with an array e.g.:

```
[
 {"name": "John",
  "email": "john@example.com"
 },
 {"name": "Jess",
  "email": "jess@example.com"
 },
 ...
]
```

you may use the following approach:

**User.java**

```
public class User {
    public String name;
    public String email;
}
```

Interface: e.g. **InterfaceAPI.java**

```
public interface InterfaceAPI {
    @GET("users")
    Call<List<User>> getUsers();
}
```

**Data provider class:**

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.example.com")
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build();

    InterfaceAPI retrofitAPI = retrofit.create(InterfaceAPI);
    Call<List<User>> call = interfaceAPI.getUsers();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<RegistrationResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<User>>call, @NonNull Response<List<User>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                // your code

            } else {
                // your code
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<User>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            //TODO
        }
    });
```

[See here more examples.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html)